# Switch button в menu java

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Возник вопрос. Как я могу сделать в menu java приложения switch кнопку (переключатель). И отследить в каком положении она сейчас находится. Если именно switch кнопку сделать нельзя, то как можно сделать какой-то другой переключатель. Нужно, чтобы была надпись и после нее переключатель. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Используйте `Switch`, для него же можно использовать listener

Comment: А как можно безошибочно вписать это все в menu?

Comment: А что за "menu java" такое?

Comment: Моя вина. Не правильно вопрос поставил. Скорее меню в java приложении

Comment: <item  android:checkable="true">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487789/how-to-add-switch-listener-in-action-bar-android

Только не забудьте заменить строку

```
Switch mainSwitchOnOffSw = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
```

На

```
SwitchCompat mainSwitchOnOffSw = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

Внутри activity_main_drawer

```
<menu>
    
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        android:title="@string/menu_notifications"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
...
```

Сам переключатель

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Только вот мне бы для именно меню, которое находится в правом верхнем углу приложения (троеточие).